# Fonts: Is there any scientific proof about the choice?

Tags: fonts, best-practices

It is common knowledge that the more you work with TeX, the more likely you are to make changes in the basic format so as to fit it in your needs. Of course, one of the most important things that people change are fonts.

Fonts are crucial in good typesetting, and like the individuals who make choices based on their preferences and rational, you expect to have the same in that aspect as well. However, this is because of the preferences that people have per se . The point is if there are studies which can prove that a font is better than another in terms of readability and easiness for the eyes, and if so, why? What are the criteria and what is the correlation between font choice and a specific font family used?

Comment: Frederic Goudy’s book “Typologia: Studies in Type Design and Type Making” contains judicious remarks on this matter.

Comment: often, the criteria for what font(s) to use have little or nothing to do with readability.  if setting a document with a great amount of math or scientific notation, or in a non-latin alphabet, it's counterproductive to choose a font that doesn't include the necessary symbols or letters, and the choice can then be very limited.  or if setting a work with a strong geographical or period connection, choosing a font associated with that location or period is "obvious".  and some readability studies have shown that "readability" depends on what the reader is used to; not helpful in this context.

Comment: While I think this is an interesting question, I'm afraid it's also off-topic.